# TypeError: from_arrays() when converting BigQuery to pandas df

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

I am trying to convert the data that I am fetching from BigQuery into pandas dataframe. My code looks like this:

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/Users/Me/Documents/credentials/google_creds.json"

# Establish the client
client = bigquery.Client(

query = """select * from bq_project.bq_table"""
df = client.query(query).to_dataframe()
```

This is the error: `TypeError: from_arrays() takes at least 2 positional arguments (1 given)` 
It errors out on `df = client.query(query).to_dataframe()` line.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install --upgrade pyarrow` then reloading jupyter notebook has solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you use conda for your other downloads, you can also use
`conda install pyarrow -c conda-forge` per the [PyPi documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/) of the pyarrow package.

Also make sure to restart your kernel!